# pip is refusing to install anything

Tags: python, pip

So I'm trying to install twillio but when I try to install it it throws this error:

```
MY_DEVICE_NAME:~ MY_NAME$ pip install twillio
Collecting twillio
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement twillio (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for twillio
You are using pip version 10.0.0b2, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
MY_DEVICE_NAME:~ MY_NAME$ pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/74/ecd13431bcc456ed390b44c8a6e917c1820365cbebcb6a8974d1cd045ab4/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
matplotlib 1.3.1 requires nose, which is not installed.
matplotlib 1.3.1 requires tornado, which is not installed.
matplotlib 1.3.1 has requirement numpy>=1.5, but you'll have numpy 1.8.0rc1 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 10.0.0b2
Uninstalling pip-10.0.0b2:

You are using pip version 10.0.0b2, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

After which I just get stuck in an infinite loop. so what should I do?

Comment: Try `pip install twilio`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:-

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

or

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Try installing from source then, get get-pip.py file from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py and then run `python get-pip.py`

Comment: sorry if this sounds dumb, but how do I install from the web?

Comment: Download get-pip.py file from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py and then open the command prompt, and run it using python `python get-pip.py`

Answer (score 3):

You made a small mistake

```
pip install twilio
```

You were trying `pip install twillio`